# How to get Solana mobile wallet adapter working

Tags: react, solana-wallet-adapter, mobile, node.js, mobile-wallet-adapter

I have created a web app using react and https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter. This works fine with the desktop wallet adapters, but I would like to use the mobile wallet adapters also so I can use the app on mobile.

So first, I install the npm package for the mobile adapter using;

```
npm i @solana-mobile/wallet-adapter-mobile
```

And then attempt to import the adapter using;

```
import { createDefaultAuthorizationResultCache, SolanaMobileWalletAdapter } from '@solana-mobile/wallet-adapter-mobile';
```

This is fine on it's own, So then I try to add the wallet to the wallets list with;

```
   const wallets = useMemo(
        () => [
            new SolanaMobileWalletAdapter({
                appIdentity: { name: 'Solana Wallet Adapter App' },
                authorizationResultCache: createDefaultAuthorizationResultCache(),
            }),
            new CoinbaseWalletAdapter(),
            new PhantomWalletAdapter(),
            new GlowWalletAdapter(),
            new SlopeWalletAdapter(),
            new SolflareWalletAdapter({ network }),
            new TorusWalletAdapter(),
        ],
        [network]
    );
```

And I get the following errors;

```
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\brook\Documents\repos\testapp\node_modules\@solana-mobile\wallet-adapter-mobile.tsx doesn't exist
```

...

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@solana-mobile/wallet-adapter-mobile' in 'C:\Users\brook\Documents\repos\testapp\src\components'
```

Where src/components is the folder that includes Wallets.tsx where this code is written.

See the image for what the node module has actually installed, I am not sure I am missing a step in installing the module?

[image: Screenshot of nodemodule]

Node Version: <s>v14.15.0</s> v16.16.0 (Updating to latest node does not help)

Comment: Tried upgrading Node?  Per nodejs.org, _Latest LTS Version: 16.16.0 (includes npm 8.11.0)_

Comment: Hey @MmmHmm. Updated to 16.16.0 and  reinstalled wallet-adapter-mobile module and it has not helped. Will update question to reflect.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's almost certainly a configuration issue with Webpack. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69302447/802047.